# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when adding refreshControl to TableViewController's subview

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview

`BrowseViewController` loads `BrowseResultsTableViewController` as `subView`. In that `subview`, is the following block of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];   
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshResults:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];

}

- (void)refreshResults:(UIRefreshControl *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"REFRESH");
    //[self performSelector:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Throwing the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 ....`

If I clean the project and rebulid, I get this error:

> 2013-03-25 23:59:06.256 rockit[40772:c07] -[UIViewControllerWrapperView refreshResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7516fe0
>       2013-03-25 23:59:06.257 rockit[40772:c07] - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewControllerWrapperView refreshResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7516fe0'

Why can't it find the method?

Comment: scope may be a problem increase the scope of instance or move to instance level

Comment: Do you use automatic reference counter ? If not, then one `retain` in needed for init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reference to `BrowseResultsTableViewController` may be getting released after you create it and the method ends. You probably need to create an instance variable inside of `BrowseViewController` that references it.

// BrowseViewController.h

```
@interface BrowseViewController : UIViewController
// ...
@property (nonatomic, strong) BrowseResultsTableViewController *browseResultsVC;
// ...
@end
```

// BrowseViewController.m

```
@implementation BrowseViewController
@synthesize browseResultsVC;
// ...
- (void)someMethod {
    self.browseResultsVC = [[BrowseResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:browseResultsVC];
}
// ...
#end
```

Comment: OMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMG! THANK YOU! I knew it was something like that and I was losing sleep over it. Now I can start my day with a smile. Thank you!